# what is mean by templating language. Why underscoreJs is required for backbone application

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, templating, underscore.js-templating

My understanding for underscoreJs is , it's a javascript library which provides helper function. i am not getting what is core functionality underscoreJs provide for backbone

Comment: Partly you are right, underscore its a toolbox with helpers plus template tool. Oh, there are a lot, you can look through backbone annotated source to clarify what underscore methods are in use.

Comment: It is a utility belt library that does loads for backbone - just look at the source. Have you ever used underscore? It has tons of helper methods that make the code shorter, it also shims stuff which is only supported by modern browsers. If you write a Backbone app you will probably find you are using it a lot too.

Answer (score 0):

Backbone is MV library, where M - model need to works with big arrays data. Underscore got a lot of methods by array and array's like objects. Underscore consists simple templating engine for small tasks. In backbone works you can use this engine for your needs.